# Accessing eureka server's dashboard deployed in windows Docker container from windows box web browser

Tags: docker, windows-10, netflix-eureka

I'm unable to access the Eureka's dashboard (deployed in windows docker) from outside the docker. However, I am able to access through POSTMAN plugin using http://192.168.99.100:8761. If I access the same url from the browser it doesn't work. I even tried with http://0.0.0.0:8761 and did not work. I even opened the port 8761 from windows firewall.

How do I solve this issue? How would I access the Eureka's dashboard deployed in windows docker from the browser outside the docker?

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
   name: eureka-server
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine 
EXPOSE 8761
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/EurekaServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Can you share the `docker run` command which you used to bring up the container?

Comment: docker run -p 8761:8761 eureka-server:latest -d

Comment: Container details:

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
868ededc07ff   eureka-server    "java -Djava.securit…"   29 minutes ago   Up 29 minutes  0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp   eureka

Comment: Do you get any output when you execute `wget http://localhost:8761`?

Comment: execute the above `wget` command within the container and also in the host and verify whether both the outputs are same.